Brake pedal to the floor with 1997 Grand Marquis after caliper upgrade
I have a 1997 Mercury Grand Marquis. It had single piston front calipers. I had a brand new set for a 2001 P71 which installed with no issues. They have two pistons per caliper.
I bled all the air from both calipers. I do not see any air bubbles when depressing the pedal and opening the valve. When the car is off, and I pump the brakes - the pedal locks which I think its a good sign.
However, when the car is on - I can push the pedal all the way to floor with not so much resistance and I am able to move the disk brake by hand.
The master cylinder bore size for both models seems to be 1inch - so that is good.
What could be the reason for not working?
Another thing - the front two abs sensors are not installed. Does the abs have anything to do with it.
I should also mention that brake pads are new, and there are no fluid leaks anywhere.

I installed the calipers on the wrong side with the bleeder on the bottom.

I went to help my brother in law bleed his '60s Corvette restoration after several failures. Unsuccessful, he phoned a friend who informed him that older Vettes have bleeders in the upper and lower assembly of calipers.........I'm familiar with brake bleeding procedures and didn't crawl under to examine calipers. I'd like to think that if I did crawl under, I might have spotted two bleeders instead of the usual single on top. Although I didn't ask him, I think he simply opened the bottoms and missed the fact that air floats to the top where the top bleeder would have aired out when opened.
